# NHibernate handling external database update

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

We have two C# projects, one is a web application and the other one is a console one. Both use **NHibernate+Fluent** to do any database manipulations. Both applications run on the same machine.

However, we are noticing that when a console app does a database update, those same objects within the web app become stale and what is more concerning, updating them within the web app and then saving them saves the stale object back to the DB, losing the update from the console app.

Is there a mechanism or a setting to prevent such behaviour without having to call the .Refresh method on each object every time we use/refer to one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use versioned entities but in the case of saving a stale entity it will merely throw an exception telling you are trying to save a stale entity.  You would need to handle this.

Nhibernate documentation on the version column:
http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-version

There are several stack overflow posts about this as well:
[When to use Nhibernate <version>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575574/when-to-use-nhibernate-version)
[How do you do Versioning in Nhibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272586/how-do-you-do-versioning-in-nhibernate)

https://ayende.com/blog/3946/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency

## Edit

If you don't want to change the way you are handling your sessions there are a couple things you can do.

Call ISession.Clear() at some point to clear everything in session out so that subsequent calls to ISession.Get will return objects from the database and not cache.

Call ISession.Evict() for a specific entity instance.  This will remove the entity from cache and subsequent calls will return objects from the database and not cache.

https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/ISession.cs

Comment: Hi Cole, thanks for the answer, it definitely addresses the problem I am facing. Would you know if there is some kind of a setting in NHibernate which would not allow it to cache all these objects so that when I retrieve them using .Get it would ALWAYS cause it to be fetched from the DB as opposed to the cache. That would already solve most of my problems without having to implement the version property.

Comment: Normally if I'm retrieving an entity from the database and the user edits it and saves it I'm using 2 sessions.  1 session to retrieve the initial information for display and the other to retrieve the update as the user saves it.  Sessions should be short lived anyway.  I think this is typically how most people do this sort of thing.

Comment: Cole, not sure I understand. I have an external application that makes changes to the application so it is in no way related to my session. I would like to force my session to cause all .Get requests to fetch from the DB as opposed to use cached (and often stale) objects. Is that configurable?

Comment: No but what you are saying is the point I'm trying to prove.  If at the point you do a .Get and you are working with a new ISession it will retrieve the entity from the database instead of the cache.  So at the point where you are ready to do the update you essentially re-retrieve the entity you are modifying and you update it's fields and commit the database update.  In this scenario there is very little room for you to get stale objects.  If you are keeping your session open for long periods of time you risk getting stale objects like you are talking about above.

Comment: Hi Cole, I understand. As I am using DI to get the whole repositories injected into my service code (along with corresponding sessions), I would like to avoid refactoring this code. Do you happen to know if there is another way of initially configuring NHibernate to force load from db on each .Get call?